Calculating Quote Line Fields Vice-Versa
Struggling with getting a solution to work for this use case -
I have two fields - Sell_Price__c and Margin_Percentage__c, I want them to be able to update each other if updated, ie if the Sell Price is updated, it should update the Margin %. Similarly, a user changing the expected Margin % should update the Sell Price.
I have tried multiple ways to essentially replicate an ISCHANGED() with a trigger, price rules and custom quote calculator plugin, but any each way seems to end up with a confliction where the field cannot be updated entirely.
Any ideas on how I can obtain this functionality?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You should be able to do this with a before-save flow.  When you say "with a trigger", does that mean you've tried a flow already?  Please [edit] your post to include the details of the flow.
